# javascript read each line into array from a modal textarea

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea id="data" class="form-control" oninput="this.style.height = ''; this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 3 +'px'"></textarea>                   
                </div>
```

and to save the user entered text from the textarea I have a save button and on click I want to save the text

```
$('#save').click(function () {
  var value = $("#data").val();
}
```

I would like the text to be stored in an array with each line an item in the array. So
text of the below would be an array of 4 items. Some line items will have a space between them but they need to be kept together as a single item in the array.

```
ABC123
XYZ 444
12323321
OOOO XXXX
```

Setting var value to be var value = []; reads each letter into an individual array item so not what I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  const value = $("#data").val();
  const splitted = value.split("\n");
  console.log(splitted);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <textarea id="data" class="form-control" oninput="this.style.height = ''; this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 3 +'px'"></textarea>                   
</div>
<button id="save-btn">save</button>
```

js:

```
const textArea = document.querySelector("#data");
const saveBtn = document.querySelector("#save-btn");

arr = [];
const saveData = function(){
  arr = textArea.value.split(/\r?\n/);
  console.log(arr);
}

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', saveData);
```

example:
https://codepen.io/huskyslava/pen/PoORBVN?editors=1111